# How to integrate Google OAuth2 MVC on a netcore1.1 project?

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-oauth

I'd like to install a Google package via NuGet that only supports .NET Framework 4.5+ while the project is like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard1.5</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
...
```

Google.Apis.Auth.Mvc
Supported Platforms:

- .NET Framework 4.5+

Google.Apis.Auth
Supported Platforms:

- .NET Framework 4.5+
- NetStandard1.3, providing .NET Core support

How to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

The MVC package is aimed at "classic" ASP.NET, not ASP.NET Core.

For ASP.NET Core, you want [Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore/) or [Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3) - but you'll need to update to either ASP.NET Core 2 or ASP.NET Core 3, as those packages *don't* support ASP.NET Core 1... and neither does Microsoft.

Comment: So the netcoreapp1.1 projects should turn into netcoreapp2.0, and the netstandard1.5 ones to netstandard2.0, right?

Comment: @Kred: I'd suggest netcoreapp2.1 rather than netcoreapp2.0, but yes for netstandard2.0.

Comment: I'm trying to upgrade like you said, but I've got an issue on startup: Application startup exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve type: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler, service name:  --->... at LightInject.ServiceContainer...

Comment: @Kred: I suggest you ask a new question that's primarily about updating from ASP.NET Core 1.x to ASP.NET Core 2.x, which is what you're really talking about at this point. The Google Auth library is incidental to the *process* of that - it's just the reason you're doing it